# How can i reuse CTE output in multiple places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have *[dbo].[fn_GetUserPublications]* function which return information about User's publications. It returns fields like Title, Desctiption, CreatedDate, etc. It does not return any information about parent/child relationships. This is my main datasource actually.

My goal is to build some kind of hierarchy. That is why i created a [Source] CTE which populates ParentPublicationID.

But i want to extend this datasource with two additional fields:

- **HasChildren** - "bit" indicating whether the ID of the current entry from the [Source] CTE is equal to the *ParentPublicationID* field of at least one entry from the same CTE.
- **ParentPublicatonUID** - "guid", which must be NULL if *ParentPublicationID* is null or when there is no entry with an ID equal to the current entry's *ParentPublicationID*. Otherwise it should be equals to the UID of the parent publication (**note: the parent publication should also be in *fn_GetUserPublications* response**)

Here is what i did:

```
WITH [Source] AS
(
    SELECT
        [UserPublication].*,
        [Publication].[ParentPublicationID] AS [ParentPublicationID]
    FROM
        [dbo].[fn_GetUserPublications](@userId) AS [UserPublication]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Publication] AS [Publication] ON 
        [UserPublication].[ID] = [Publication].[ID]
),    
[SourceWithParent] AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [SourcePublication].ID,
        [ParentPublication].[UID] AS [ParentUID]
    FROM
        [Source] AS [SourcePublication]
    INNER JOIN [Source] AS [ParentPublication] ON
        [ParentPublication].[ID] = [SourcePublication].[ParentPublicationID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Publication] AS [Publication] ON
        [Publication].[ID] = [ParentPublication].[ID]
),
[SourceWithChildren] AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [SourcePublication].[ID],
        CAST (
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT([ChildPublication].[ID]) > 0
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END 
            AS bit
        ) AS [HasChildren]
    FROM
        [Source] AS [SourcePublication]
    LEFT JOIN [Source] AS [ChildPublication] ON
        [ChildPublication].[ParentPublicationID] = [SourcePublication].[ID]
    GROUP BY [SourcePublication].[ID]
)

SELECT
    [Source].*,
    [SourceWithParent].[ParentUID],
    [SourceWithChildren].[HasChildren]
FROM 
    [Source]
LEFT JOIN [SourceWithParent] ON
    [SourceWithParent].[ID] = [Source].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [SourceWithChildren] ON
    [SourceWithChildren].[ID] = [Source].[ID]
```

This code works but there is one problem. My *fn_GetUserPublications* function is called **5 times** in this script (probably because *Source* CTE is called 5 times).
[image]
This is the beginning of the execution plan. Can't attach full plan because it's quite big and it contains some names from my PROD database. But it shows that he same function was called 5 times

How can i achieve the same by calling *fn_GetUserPublications* function only once (by calling CTE once) and then just reusing the output?

Comment: Interesing question. I would be curious what execution plan SQL Server is selecting. Can you post it?

Comment: Full plan is quite big. Can't attach it here. It also contains some names from my PROD db. Provided just the beginning of plan

Comment: Can you post the plan in [pastetheplan.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) or [checktheplan.com](https://checktheplan.com/?engine=sqlserver) ?

Comment: Insert the function output into a `#temp` table and join to that. Probably you could optimise this further and remove some or all of the repeated joins.

Comment: Although I've failed to grok in fullness your question, there may be another approach with questionable performance. As you already know, you can nest CTEs and reference them repeatedly within a single query. You may be able to arrange the final query to perform the five `select`s you need and `union all` the results. An additional hard-coded column, e.g. `'AuthorQuery' as QueryName`, would let you separate the resulting rows.

Comment: This looks like a multi-statement table valued function and that function is not tied to the data in the CTE where it is called.  I would convert that function to an inline-table valued function and see how that changes the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the function output into a #temp table and join to that.  SQL Server doesn't have a SPOOL/CACHE/MATERIALIZE query hint.

eg

```
SELECT
    [UserPublication].*,
    [Publication].[ParentPublicationID] AS [ParentPublicationID]
INTO #SOURCE
FROM
    [dbo].[fn_GetUserPublications](@userId) AS [UserPublication]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Publication] AS [Publication] ON 
    [UserPublication].[ID] = [Publication].[ID];

WITH [Source] AS
(
  SELECT * FROM #SOURCE
),   . . .
```